# insert/replace table by value range criteria in excel

Tags: excel

I have 6 different tables(22 rows and 14 columns) with different discounts for multiple services who depends of purchases amount.

I need to make one worksheet, where cell containing value, who is entered by user, automatically changes whole discount table.
For example i enter in A1 cell 15 and who table gets updated to Table2 discounts.

Table1 discounts get in efect if cell value 0-9;

Table2 discounts get in efect if cell value 10-20;

Table3 .......

Discount tables are already pre-made and i just need to change table by criteria who was entered.
I think VLOOKUP could do a job here but im not sure about it, and on the other hand that will require a lot of vlookup formula usage what will make reload much longer and eat more PC resources.
Maybe there is some other way how to swap all table by one action?

Comment: try search the use of INDEX+MATCH which does the same job as VLOOKUP but consumes less PC resource.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no sample data/info given, only a specific table size.. Then I'll focus on this part only.

> is some other way how to swap all table by one action?

Assuming the 6 tables are located at A2:N21 of Sheet1 to Sheet6. In A2 of Sheet7 put :

```
=INDIRECT($A$1&"!"&CELL("address",A2),TRUE)
```

and drag until N21. Type in "Sheet1" in A1 to test.

Please share if it works/not.